# I need help with this equation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve $z^3(z-i)-1-2z^2-z^4=0$.
I got $z^4-iz^3-1-2z^2-z^4=0$ and then $-iz^3-1-2z^2=0$ but now I don't know how to continue to find the three solutions.

Could anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $z=i$ is one root. Factor out $(z-i)$ to find the other two roots.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. How can i factor out (z-i)?

Comment: @kevin_712 Write $-iz^{3}-1-2z^{2} $ as $(-i)(z-i) (z^{2}+az+b)$. Equate the constant terms and the  coefficients of $z$ and $z^{2}$ to find out what $a$ and $b$ are. Then solve the quadratic equation $z^{2}+az+b=0$.

Comment: Alright, thank you!!!

Comment: You should get $a=-i$ and $b=1$.